# Secure review form to use https

Tags: review, ssl, secure

We've placed our shop behind ssl (https) and I've also secured the contact form (Created a custom module and added `<contacts>/contact</contacts>` to the `<secure_url>` section in `config.xml`). But I can't figure out how to do the same for the review form.

Any tips?

Comment: is you want to https for this module?

Comment: `We've placed our shop behind ssl (https)` You could set https for the default url so the whole show only works with https.

Answer (score 2):

If you want secure URL for custom then
add below in `config.xml` file

```
<secure_url>
       <identifier>you_ModuoflefrontaName</identifier>
</secure_url>
```

So example

```
...
    <!--
    @ start of define define frontend routers
    -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>custommodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
        <!--
        @ create a layout file for this module
        -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommodule>
                    <file>custommodule.xml</file>
                </custommodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
     <secure_url>
            <custommodule>/custommodule</custommodule>
        </secure_url>

    </frontend>

...
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do it is to add this to your config.xml inside the `<frontend>` tag:

```
<secure_url>
    <review>/review</review>
</secure_url>
```

Full tree would look like this (excluding all the other configurations you have):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <frontend>
       <secure_url>
           <review>/review</review>
       </secure_url>
    </frontend>
</config>
```